# How To Read \n(enter) and \b(space) from a file and store it in an array of characters using java

Tags: java

I want to read data from a file including the space and enter and store it in an array of characters. please help me to solve this problem

Comment: \b is not a space, it's a backspace; and you will not normally find such a character in a text file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileReader http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html. Its contract is:

> Convenience class for reading
>   character files. The constructors of
>   this class assume that the default
>   character encoding and the default
>   byte-buffer size are appropriate. To
>   specify these values yourself,
>   construct an InputStreamReader on a
>   FileInputStream.
>
> FileReader is meant for reading
>   streams of characters. For reading
>   streams of raw bytes, consider using a
>   FileInputStream.

This will preserve the \n and other characters.

Also consider using the Apache library http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

where the method http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29

```
public static String readFileToString(File file)
                               throws IOException
```

> Reads the contents of a file into a
>   String using the default encoding for
>   the VM. The file is always closed.

To get the character array, use the String method http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29

```
public char[] toCharArray()
```

> ```
> Converts this string to a new character array.
>
> Returns:
>     a newly allocated character array whose length is the length of
> ```
>
> this string and whose contents are
>   initialized to contain the character
>   sequence represented by this string.

If this is not what you want you will need to explain further

Answer (score 0):

You can try [FileUtils.readFileToString(filename)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29)
e.g.

```
String allTextInFile = FileUtils.readFileToString("my-file.txt");
```